# How can I edit (in MS Expression Web ) FrontPage Site Parameters (Substitutions)?

Tags: web-development

Or, asked another way:

Where are the values for MS Front Page Substitions (Site Parameters) stored? (so that I can edit in Web Expressions)

Background
I'm ashamed to admit that I've been maintaining our company's website in MS FrontPage for over 9 years. I'm moving it to Expression Web, which will display the Substitutions (stored as Site Parameters) but I can't figure out where to **edit** them.

**I tried** searching the source folders for the website (on my development PC) for the name of the parameter (s-Variable=*hoursOfOperation*) but did not find it (other than in the files it was actually *used in*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FrontPage Substitutions are stored in a text file:
_vti_pvt\service.cnf

You can just edit it with notepad. Obviously, pay attention to how they format it. I'd recommend that if you're adding a substitution, copy an existing one and change it.

Answer (score 1):

**[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160418070246/http://download.microsoft.com:80/download/f/f/2/ff2d736a-9ec6-4e3b-b094-d782aa7cda72/microsoft_frontpage_to_expression_web.doc)** is a doc file.

Also have a look at;

**[Migrating from Microsoft FrontPage to Microsoft Expression Web - Part1](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006042754/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xweb/archive/2008/10/03/updating-your-site-with-standards_2d00_compliant-html.aspx)**

**[Microsoft Expression Web: Taking Over From Frontpage and Taking On Adobe](https://web.archive.org/web/20110830193502/http://www.readwriteweb.com:80/archives/microsoft_expression_web.php)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: I read 'em. They don't address how to *edit* the Site Parameters.